# FindBugs eclipse Properties view does not show Detail Description

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

I just installed FindBug 2.0.0 in Eclipse Indigo. The Bug Explorer works fine, but I can't get a very useful view of the bug details. If I select a bug in the Bug Explorer, all related info is displayed in the Properties view, but what I'd really like to see is just a summary - i.e. don't want to have to bore down through the entire Properties data structure. In particular, I'd like to see the Detail description (available as Data -> DetailHTML, Data -> DetailPlainText and Data -> DetailText in the Properties view). The DetailText is too long to be displayed entirely, so you would have to cut and paste it to read more about the bug.

I assume that the Bug Info view is intended to provide this information, but when I open this view and select a bug in the Bug Explorer, nothing appears in Bug Info.

BTW - I have the same problem for the Problems view: how do you look at a long description without doing copy + paste?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I right-click on the bug in the Bug Explorer view and select Show Bug Info.  That displays it in the Bug Info view.

Also, in the java editor if I click on the bug icon on the left side, it also takes me to the Bug Info view.

This is with FindBugs 2.0.0 and eclipse 3.7.1.

Comment: Hi. After I asked this question, I discovered the "click the bug icon on the left side." I just tried the right-click in the Bug Explorer view, but was not offered the Show Bug Info choice. But, my problem is now solved, so that's not important. Thanks for your help.